# implicitly call a method

Tags: java

I learn java by self, I trapped at point about `implicitly call another method` 
I can't figure out `how dealCard method call ToString method implicitly` 
  in Card Shuffling and Dealing Simulation.

```
 public class Card 
    {
       private String face;
       private String suit; 

       public String toString() 
       { 
          return face + " of " + suit;
       } // end method toString
}
```

// DeckOfCards class represents a deck of playing cards.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class DeckOfCards
{
   public Card dealCard()
   {
      // determine whether Cards remain to be dealt
      if ( currentCard < deck.length )
         return deck[ currentCard++ ];
      else        
         return null;
   } 
}
```

// execute application

```
public class DeckOfCardsTest
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      DeckOfCards myDeckOfCards = new DeckOfCards();
      myDeckOfCards.shuffle(); // place Cards in random order

      // print all 52 Cards in the order in which they are dealt
      for ( int i = 1; i <= 52; i++ )
      {
         // dealCard method implicitly call ToString method 
         System.out.printf( "%-19s", myDeckOfCards.dealCard() );
      }
```

Comment: Did you understand inheritance?

Comment: @Rafael Teles where do you see inheritance? o_O

Comment: No, what I read from book literally " Method toString creates a String consisting of the face of the card,+ " of " + and the suit of the card.

Called implicitly when the object is used where a String is expected.

Comment: thank a lot for all of these answers

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis there is inheritance in every Class in Java, all classes inherit from Object. I asked that, because I need that information to give a complete response for the question, because if he don't understand inheritance how could he understand where the toString() comes from?

Answer (score 3):

The `dealCard` method does not implicitly call `toString`. It just returns a card from your deck.

The implicit call to `toString()` is done by the `printf` method, that you invoked from your `main` method:

```
System.out.printf( "%-19s", myDeckOfCards.dealCard() );
```

Whenever you pass something of type `Object` to the printf method and it is not a type that the `printf` method knows about (it knows about numbers, for example), then it uses the `toString()` method to obtain a String representation of your object.

Answer (score 1):

> System.out.printf( "%-19s", myDeckOfCards.dealCard() );

You are printing a String (%s) so Java will look for the `toString()` method of your `Card` class.

The `toString()` method will returns the string that represent the object.
If you not override this method (part of the `Object` class) you will see a strange string which is the representation that Java is giving by default at your object

Answer (score 0):

Println(Object obj) method tries to convert that object into String as below
 String s = String.valueOf(x);

String.valueof(object) will check if object is null, prints null else Object.toString() method will be invoked.